# Proxy a request - get a parameter from URL, add a header and update request URL using Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, header, http-proxy

I am looking for a way to do the following using Nginx:

1. Intercept a request
2. Read URL, parse it and read a value from it.
3. Add that value as a new request header
4. Update the URL (remove a particular value)
5. Forward the request to another server

e.g

```
Request URL - http://<<nginx>>/test/001.xml/25
Final URL - http://<<server>>/test/001.xml with header (x-replica: 25)
```

I have a nginx server setup with a upstream for the actual server. I was wondering how do I setup Nginx to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data exists within the request URI itself (available by the `$uri` variable in nginx), you can parse that using the nginx lua module. nginx will need to be compiled with lua for this to work, see: [openresty's nginx lua module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module).

From there you can use the `set_by_lua_block` or `set_by_lua_file` [directive](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) given `$uri` as a parameter.

In configuration this would look something like:

```
location / {
    ...
    set_by_lua_file $var_to_set /path/to/script.lua $uri;
    # $var_to_set would contain the result of the script from this point
    proxy_set_header X-Replica $var_to_set;
    ...
}
```

In `script.lua` we can access the `$uri` variable from in the `ngx.arg` list (see [these docs](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxarg)):

```
function parse_uri( uri )
    parsed_uri = uri
    -- Parse logic here
    return parsed_uri
end

return parse_uri( ngx.arg[1] )
```

Similarly, you can modify this function or create another to make a variable with the updated `$uri`.